# Branded YouTube Channel: Element Inconsistency

Tags: youtube

I am working on a branded YouTube channel for a pharmaceutical client. We have a content block on the right hand side the has auto-scrolling copy. (Highlighted in red below)

[image]

It was implemented years ago by someone whom no longer works with the company, and the channel "went dark" (made private) for the last two years. The content block with the scrolling copy not only shows on the channel itself, but also on the right of the videos on the video specific pages... or so it did up until a week ago.

[image]

It just stopped appearing on the video specific pages. I am unable to pinpoint why it stopped appearing. To be completely honest, I don't even know how it was implemented into the channel to begin with - I have zero documentation on its implementation, nor a contact to be able to reach out to.

**Question:** Does anyone have any experience with implementing custom elements to branded YouTube channels, like the one I'm having issues with, that might be able to point me in right direction on how to resolve this?